# Concating json with grunt-contrib-concat is not setting the separator

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have several json-files I want to concat, but the seperator is not inserted in the final file.

The concat part of my gruntfile:

```
    concat: {
        options: {
            seperator: ','
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['src/texts/*.json'],
            dest: 'dist/texts.json'
        }
    }
```

Sample of the produced file:

```
{
  "name": "Bavaria Ipsum",
  "source": "bavaria-ipsum.de",
  "sourceLink": "http://bavaria-ipsum.de/",
  "license": "Other",
  "licenseLink": "http://bavaria-ipsum.de/about.html",
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, …"
}

{
  "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
  "source": "Unknown",
  "sourceLink": "",
  "license": "none",
  "licenseLink": "",
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, …"
}
```

Is my gruntfile wrong or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `a` in word `separator` not `seperator`